# Getting prefix of a namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm developing an application and I need to add several elements into the header of soap message I receive. The problem is I don't know which prefix the namespace I'm using for adding these elements is using, but it's sure there will be several elements in the body using this prefix, so the namespace is already declared in the message.

For example, I'm receiving this message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:operation>
      </urn:operation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the xpath expression I use for adding these elements in the header is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="Getsed">aBcDeFgHiJkLmNñOpQrStUvWxYz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Header']">  
        <xsl:copy>
           <urn:SH xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
             <urn:sed><xsl:value-of select="$Getsed"/></urn:sed>
           </urn:SH>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to use the prefix (urn) already declared for the namespace `urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com`.

Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: Your question is not clear, esp. this part: "*The problem is I don't know which prefix the namespace I'm using for adding these elements is using,..*". As a rule, the prefixes are unimportant - what matters, in both input and output, is the namespaces (URIs) themselves. If you know these, then you know all that you need to know and you can avoid awkward (and inefficient!) expressions such as `*[local-name()='Header']`.

Comment: You can't avoid some of those awkward expressions if you are trying to match nodes with no namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a silly workaround like `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(//*[namespace-uri() = 'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com']), ':')" />` will fit your needs.

Thus your template can be rewrited that way:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Header']">
    <!-- this will retrieve the namespace prefix in source document -->
    <xsl:variable name="ns-sforce">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(//*[namespace-uri() = 'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com']), ':')" />
    </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:copy>
         <!-- create prefixed elements with the same value as before -->
         <xsl:element name="{$ns-sforce}:SH" namespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
           <xsl:element name="{$ns-sforce}:sed" namespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
             <xsl:value-of select="$Getsed"/>
           </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>

         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note: `<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Header']"> can be replaced by <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Header']">`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works great!! Sorry but I can't asset this answer as useful as my own reputation doesn't reach 15.